# Views automatically adds = inside link when output as link

Tags: views, feeds, navigation

I am trying to create a view of the latest posts from a vbulletin forum through external.php.

As external.php can publish both in RSS and XML format, I have installed views_xml_backend in order to show a view of the content.

it works perfectly when the link is shown as normal text and if you copy the URL into your browser it would redirect to the latest post of the thread.
Example:
http://foo.com/showthread.php?topic-name&goto=newpost

However, when i want to parse the result as a link it automatically inserts a = right before  &, which means that the link does not work. 
So the  looks like this: 
[link text](http://foo.com/showthread.php?topic-name**=**&goto=newpost)

I have tried in so many ways to fix this, but i have no idea what to do. 
Perhaps a small snippet could do it?

Modules: 
views 3x-3.10
views_xml_backend 7x-1.0-alpha4

Comment: In that URL the = should be valid. Does it really insert the 4 asterisks too? http://foo.com/showthread.php?topic-name=&goto=newpost Are you using Feeds module or not? Looks like not just reading XML directly from the bulletin XML. The external.php you mention is this? https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/vboptions_group_external

Comment: no, just using feeds module as i do not want to have every item saved as a node. Using the views_xml_backend module instead which can read from an XML data source

Comment: You can see the example live here: http://forum.oldtrafford.dk/showthread.php?4011-MoM-Everton-Manchester-United=&goto=newpost 
If you delete the = before &, it works

Comment: But Feeds module **does** create a node per item. So you're not using feeds?

Comment: No, i am not using feeds. Sorry for the confusion. Not sure why i wrote that. I am not using feeds as i do not want to create a node for each record.